# Loading (as data that can be transferred) and saving (reconstructing from the data) RAR files. [Python]

Tags: python, zip, rar

I want to load a RAR file to Python in a way that I can transfer that data and reconstruct it again later. I am looking for something (binary code maybe ?) that can be loaded and reconstructed regardless of what is inside the RAR file.
I read about some libbers that may help me like "zipfile" but I couldn't find a way to load it in a way that I could transfer the data and rebuild it again.
Any ideas?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [pyReScene](https://bitbucket.org/Gfy/pyrescene) to back up the meta data of RAR files in Python. The result is a SRR file. With that SRR file the original RAR can be recreated again at a later time if the same contents are available. You can find more info about this process on the [ReScene wiki](http://rescene.wikidot.com/).

If you just want to extract RAR files with Python, have a look at [rarfile](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/rarfile/).